# Unable to connect via TLS

Tags: email, configuration, smtp

I can't figure out what's happening here. Can anyone please explain a solution to me in simple terms?

exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect via TLS' in /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:211

Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#1 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#2 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#3 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(470): Zend_Mail->send()
#4 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php(527): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#5 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Mailer.php(84): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('customer_passwo...', 'support', Array, Array, Array, '4')
#6 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(680): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#7 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(697): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->_sendEmailTemplate('customer/passwo...', 'customer/passwo...', Array, '4')
#8 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(741): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail()
#9 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Customer_AccountController->forgotPasswordPostAction()
#10 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('forgotpasswordp...')
#11 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /home/mywebsiteco/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

Comment: `Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')` you are trying to connect to the localhost via TLS?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'm guessing it can be a simple reason. Just check if the email id you are using to send emails is existing on your email server. For e.g. you may be sending it from orders@yourwebsite.com and you may not have created the orders@yourwebsite.com email on your email server.